# Jmeter Requests Failing at 30th sec or Latency is at 30 secs

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

As I am increasing the load, the request which are failing to get a response is increasing and for 99% of the requests which are failing has a latency 0f 30 secs. Can anyone please help me with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AquOF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Help you with what? Fixing your application [bottlenecks](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)?

If the issue is not reproducible with 1 user or lesser load (I see successful requests with up to 50 seconds response time) it means that your application is overloaded and cannot handle 70 concurrent users.

The reasons could be in:

- Lack of resources on application under test side, check if there's enough CPU, RAM, etc. It can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
- Inspect your application logs and configuration, it might be the case it needs to be tuned for high loads
- If there is an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) - check application/database/middleware metrics. If not - consider re-running your test with [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tool telemetry enabled

With regards to your JMeter test:

- [Don't run your test in GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), it's only for scripts development and debugging
- [Remove all the listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean), they don't add any value and just consume valuable resources